# how to split a string TWICE

Tags: c#, split

I've been trying to split a string twice but I keep getting the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

This is the string I intend to split:

```
"a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^"
```

such that I use the `"^"` as a delimiter in the first array separation so that each set will look as follows after the first result

```
a*b*c*d*e 1*2*3*4*5 e*f*g*h*i
```

Then thereafter perform another split operation on this set with `*` as the separator so that the results, for example from the first set is `a b c d e`

This is the C# code:

```
words = "a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^";

char[] del = { '^' };

string[] splitResult = words.Split(del);
foreach (string w in splitResult)
{
    char[] separator = { '*' };
    string[] splitR = w.Split(separator);
    foreach (string e in splitR)
    {
        string first = splitR[0];
        string second = splitR[1];
        string third = splitR[2];
        string fourth = splitR[3];
        string fifth = splitR[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried words.Split(del, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);? Is the output after the first split empty?

Comment: You should check if the splitR-array contains 5 elements as expected.  The problem is that the last w contains no data (because of the last '^')

Comment: @David thanks,the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries is what i was missing

Comment: What is the function of the inner foreach loop? Since you do not use `e` anywhere it would appear that it is useless.

Answer (score 5):

To remove the last part where there is no result, how about

In C#

```
string str = "a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^";
var result = str.Split(new char[] { '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split('*')).ToArray();
```

In VB.Net

```
Dim str As String = "a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^"
Dim result = str.Split(New Char() {"^"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(Function(x) x.Split("*")).ToArray()
```

Comment: +1, fix single quotes in var result = d.Split('^').Select(x => x.Split('*'));

Comment: might also to .ToArray() to give him what he wanted

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Linq:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> strings = words
    .Split(new char[] { '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(w => w.Split('*'));
```

or if you prefer to work exclusively with arrays

```
string[][] strings = words
    .Split(new char[] { '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(w => w.Split('*').ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string words= "a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^";
 string[] reslts = words.Split(new char[] { '*', '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a terminating separator, So the final string is empty.

```
If (w != null) {                   
string[] splitR = w.Split(separator);
      If splitR.lenght > 4)
      {
               string first = splitR[0];
               string second = splitR[1];
               string third = splitR[2];
               string fourth = splitR[3];
               string fifth = splitR[4];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception `Index was outside the bounds of the array` because in the last loop, it is getting only one item, I suggest you to check for five items:

```
words = "a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^";
char[] del = { '^' };

string[] splitResult = words.Split(del);
foreach (string w in splitResult)
{
    char[] separator = { '*' };
    string[] splitR = w.Split(separator);
    if (splitR.Length>=5)
    {
        foreach (string e in splitR)
        {
            string first = splitR[0];
            string second = splitR[1];
            string third = splitR[2];
            string fourth = splitR[3];
            string fifth = splitR[4];
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string words = "a*b*c*d*e^1*2*3*4*5^e*f*g*h*i^";

char[] del = { '^' };

string[] splitResult = words.Split(del,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string w in splitResult)
{
    char[] separator = { '*' };
    string[] splitR = w.Split(separator);
    if(splitR.Length==5)
    {
        string first = splitR[0];
        string second = splitR[1];
        string third = splitR[2];
        string fourth = splitR[3];
        string fifth = splitR[4];

        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", first, second, third, fourth, fifth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line does it all

```
var f = words.Split(new char[] { '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '*' }).ToArray())
             .ToArray();
```

Your second loop does 5 times same thing (you don't use `e`).

The exception you got is because a last empty string was included resulting in an empty array that gave the index out of range exception in the inner loop.